# Scala type that is Iterable and has a length?

Tags: scala, types, size, iterable

Writing Scala code, I regularly encounter cases where I have "processor" functions that operate iteratively on a collection of elements and also need to know the length of the collection.

On the other hand I have "provider" functions that generate collections and so already know the length. The generated collections may be `List[T]`, `Array[T]` or `Set[T]`, etc., but even in the case of `List[T]`, my generator knows the size (even if the `List` type does not store it).

So I would naturally declare the "processor" functions as taking the most generic type that seems to fit all collection types, `Iterable[T]`, as a parameter. However, they then internally need to find out the size via iterative collection traversal at a cost of O(N), which is undesirable.

So my naive solution would be to create a new type like `IterableWithSize[T]` and have the provider and processor functions create and take this type. Neither `Seq[T]` nor `IndexedSeq[T]` seem to fit the bill. But this seems like a relatively common use case, so I'm suspecting that there is a more idiomatic way to do this. What would that be?

Comment: I don't understand why `IndexedSeq[T]` doesn't work for you…

Comment: Since you actually want to store extra data within the collection, I would think that your naive way to do this would be best.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Set[T] isn't a IndexedSeq[T]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is an idiomatic way to do this. But here are two alternatives:

(1) Extend Scala's List/Set/Array collections and override the size method. This is not as difficult as it seems at first glance.

(2) Wrap your List/Set/Array collections together with the size and define an implicit unwrapper like:

```
class IterableWithSizeWrapper[E](private val c: Iterable[E], val size: Int)
object IterableWithSizeWrapper {
  implicit def unwrap[E](iws: IterableWithSizeWrapper[E]): Iterable[E] = iws.c
}

object ListWithSizeTest {

  def process[E](iws: IterableWithSizeWrapper[E]) {
        // iws.size uses your cached size value
        // iws.take(i) forces the unwrap to the original collect
        // so iws.take(i).size takes the calculated size
    for (i <- 0 to iws.size) assert(iws.take(i).size == i)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    process(new IterableWithSizeWrapper(List(1,2,3), 3))
    process(new IterableWithSizeWrapper(Set(1,2,3), 3))
    process(new IterableWithSizeWrapper(Array(1,2,3), 3))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Scala collections, performance sensitive methods like `size` are not inherited from traits but overridden in the bottom type. For example see the implementation of `immutable.HashSet`:

https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_1/src//library/scala/collection/immutable/HashSet.scala

So you don't need to care about it. Just define an high-level common trait like `Traversable` or `Iterable` and you're done.

Comment: Well, not quite: I already know that the bottom type in some cases will be 'List[T]', which does not store size information, resulting in an O(N) operation (list traversal). Since for the purpose of the question I assume that I always have the size available, I really do need a special type that holds the collection size.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, there's no idiomatic way around that. Scala collections were really meant to be traversed or used in other prescribed manners (such as `Set.contains` or `Map.get`). Checking for size is not part of them, and some of them are not even finite.

Now, `IndexedSeq` is a relatively safe bet -- it guarantees O(logn) indexed access, which is only possible if you have O(logn) size. Also, `Set` and `Map` are reasonably safe as well, for similar reasons. But if you are looking for a trait that gives you a guarantee on `size` speed, there isn't one.

Answer (score 1):

How about `Traversable`? All your collections you mention inherit from it (`Array` indirectly via `WrappedArray`) and it provides `size` and `toIterable` (or `toIterator`) for traversal.

Comment: I considered Traversable, too. But (a) it is more primitive and not iterable (I can only do foreach() for all elements, so I cannot operate on some prefix) and (b) it also does not have size information **stored**, so I'd still end up doing a collection traversal at cost O(N) to determine the size. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No `Traversable` isn't an iterable, but it has the mentioned methods to provide it. Generally a trait/super-class can't really specify how a getter method is implemented, thus whether the returned size is stored or calculated, or whether the returned Iterable isn't a full copy instead of a thin wrapper. Even its derivations List and Set can't guarantee that. Those kinds of things you have to establish yourself in an interface contract and make sure that you only use sub-classes that adhere to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor functions should accept `Seq[T]`.  A `Seq` is precisely an `Iterable` that "has a length".  Your only remaining problem is making `length` efficient.  AFAIK it is already efficient in all cases except for `List`.  To make `List.length` efficient just do as the others describe:  Create an implementation of `Seq` that wraps a `List` and stores its length.